# Do quotients of amenable groups C*-algebras satisfy the UCT?

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, kt.k-theory-and-homology, c-star-algebras, amenability

Let G be a discrete amenable group.

**General Question:** Let $J$ be an ideal of $C^*(G)$, the group C*-algebra of $G.$  Does $C^*(G)/J$ satisfy the universal
 coefficient theorem (UCT)?

I am mainly interested in the following special case:

**Specific Question:** Same as the above question, but suppose moreover that G is finitely generated, nilpotent and $J$ is
 the kernel of an irreducible
 representation.

I know embarrassingly little about the UCT.  I'm aware of Tu's 1999 paper  "La conjecture de Baum-Connes pour
  les feuilletages moyennables" from which (I'm told) it follows that amenable groupoid C*-algebras satisfy the UCT, the various constructions that
   preserve the UCT ($\mathbb{Z}$-actions, inductive limits, two out of three property), and little else.

EDIT: Elizabeth Gillaspy and I recently showed the answer to the specific question is "yes"     arXiv:1510.05469 [math.OA].  I still don't have any idea for the general case.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this question?

Comment: @YemonChoi No,  I just found several "I'm sure that's true"s from experts

Comment: This might be a difficult question because even taking $J$ to be trivial the question is whether the rather arbitrary amenable $C^*$-Algebra $C^*(G)$ satisfies UCT. But it is unsettled if every amenable (separable) $C^*$-Algebra is in the boot strap class.

Comment: @hansel The case you mention was settled by Tu in the paper I quoted in the original post.

Comment: @Caleb: thanks, interesting. I am suspicious that the general case might not hold because perhaps you Need 2 out of 3 property, and $C^*(G)/J$ might for example not be amenable.

Comment: @hansel Quotients of amenable C*-algebras are amenable.